# [Vue warn]: The "data" option should be a function that returns a per-instance value in component definitions

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Estoy aprendiendo Laravel y VueJs pero en este sencillo ejemplo me esta devolviendo un error la consola:

```
[Vue warn]: The "data" option should be a function that returns a per-instance value in component definitions.
```

El codigo es este:

```
<template>
    <h1>Mensaje: {{ message }}</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            message: 'Hola mundo'
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

Porque me devuelve este error si este devolviendo data como un objeto?
Gracias

Comment: Hola, estoy tratando de reproducir esto, pero no me tira ningún warning. Lo probé en un proyecto laravel y también hice un [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-swirles-siyps?file=/index.html) pero tu código funciona perfectamente. ¿Es posible que estés cargando otro componente además del que muestras?

Answer (score 2):

Como lo indica el error: La opción "datos" debe ser una función, Entonces, al definir un componente, data debe declararse como una función que devuelve el objeto de datos inicial.

```
<template>
    <h1>Mensaje: {{ message }}</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data:function(){ 
        return {
            message: 'Hola mundo'
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

[Documentación oficial sobre su duda y el por qué de la misma](https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/#Why-does-data-need-to-be-a-function)

Comment: No existen problemas con las arrow functions?, recuerdo haber leido alguna sección de la doc que indica que no se use ya que el scope que dan ambas es distinto y el acceso a las propiedades del objeto data pudieran dar undefined, es duda

Comment: Siii, al declarar métodos (props ejemplo) de Vue no use arrow function, debido a que estas enlazan el contexto principal por this y marcara indefinido. Lo mejor seria ES5 con data:function(){}

Comment: Pues haciendolo asi sigue arrojando el mismo error

Comment: @Alberto me gustaría tomar el comentario de @ porloscerros Ψ y preguntarle lo mismo. Ya que si tomo el ejemplo de respuesta probando en codeSanbox funciona correctamente

Comment: Gracias, me ayudo bastante.